# this.props.stats.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In the console i am receiving back data from an API: https://github.com/SunDwarf/OWAPI/blob/master/api.md

but in the file where i am trying to render it to the page i am getting back an error : this.props.stats.map is not a function
previously i did it like this for a weather app and didn't have a problem so i am not sure where to look to figure this out.
*EDIT: added curly brackets to function mapStateToProps({ stats }) which now changes the error to "TypeError: Cannot read property 'achievements' of undefined"
does this mean the path to the info is incorrect?

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class OverwatchStats extends Component {
  renderStats(achievementData) {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{achievementData.data.eu.achievements.support}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }

  render() {
   return (
     <table className="table table-hover">
       <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Hero Achievements</th>
           <th>Got</th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.stats.map(this.renderStats)}
       </tbody>
     </table>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ stats }) {
  return { stats };
    }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OverwatchStats);
```

I have my code here: [My Github](https://github.com/KadenLag/overwatchStats)

Comment: What's in `stats`? E.g., you have to make sure that you have something in `stats` to map over. It's impossible to help further without knowing the data and the reducer.

Comment: Is `stats` a json?

Comment: Show your this.props.stats

Comment: In the stats reducer, what is your initial state?

Answer (score 0):

According to the api, *stats* is the object, not the array, so you can't map over it

Answer (score 0):

Eldar G hit the nail right on the head.

Because stats is an object that outputs the following

```
var stats = {"stats": {
    "typeofstat" : {},
    "othertypeofstat": {}
    ...
}
```

You can do the following in order to iterate all keys of an object.

```
Object.keys(this.props.stats).map((key) => {
    var currentStat = stats[key];
    //do stuff with currentStat
});
```

Read https://github.com/SunDwarf/OWAPI/blob/master/api.md#get-apiv3ubattletagstats if you want more information on the type of keys that each stat contains. It seems your response will be a deeply nested object. Interpret and manipulate such an object according to your preferences and requirements.

Hope this helps. Remember, **all iterator methods like map, forEach, reduce, etc... work only for arrays!**

Comment: not only `map`, all iterator like **map, forEach, reduce, for etc works only for array**.